# SEO - google keywords issue. Can anyone shed any light on this for me?

Tags: google, keywords

I launched my site a few months ago, it have been indexed by google for most of the keywords I had in mind. The only thing is, one of the most important keywords of all is not showing up in webmaster tools as a keyword. This is causing me a real pain, as people will not find my site. My SEO skills are usually effective, which is why this has stumped me. It's for my web design website. The keyword(s) i'm missing are web and website.

As my site is about web design, the design on it's own will not help! I have noticed my word count on website and web are quite high, but that's naturally occurring. I didn't fill it with junk, because I don't think that's the best way. Is this some sort of google procedure to block the keyword "website". I am just re-designing my site and re-writing all content in effort to solve this issue.

Can anyone give me any advice on this problem? [Here is my website](http://www.ransomedesign.co.uk/web/)

Comment: I just noticed this question may not be allowed on stackoverflow as it's not a question about code/programming. Sorry about that, not sure how to delete the post so maybe a moderator could do the honours for me :D

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot do individual site reviews for SEO here. If  you want SEO tips read up on the [SEO questions in this website](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo). Then if you have specific questions feel free to ask them here.